# Roblox API - What is the "cursor" argument

Tags: http, roblox

In the roblox API documentation (not to be confused with roblox's lua documentation) there is an argument for some GET request operations, for example https://inventory.roblox.com/v2/users/2333/inventory?assetTypes=Model&cursor=idk&limit=10&sortOrder=Asc . What are the cursors/how do they work?

I'm making a huge project that'll make using the roblox API way easier, but I don't know the cursors so there is a lot less I can do.

Roblox API documentation [here](https://api.roblox.com/docs?useConsolidatedPage=true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a concept called pagination. Pagination is when a website is split up into different pages. This helps Roblox and other websites not give back an unnecessary amount of information.

Once you send a request to Roblox which may return more than whatever limit you have specified entries you will get a cursor value. You can then send another request with that cursor value you were just given to get the next page of values.